# Homography matrix of two boards on same plane

Tags: computer-vision

### The theory

homography is defined like this:
$H=1/r_3*\begin{bmatrix}  
f_{x} & 0 & C_x\\  
0 & f_{y} & C_y\\  
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}  
t_{11} & t_{12} &  r_{1}\\  
t_{21} & t_{22} &  r_{2}\\  
t_{31} & t_{32} &  r_{3}\\
\end{bmatrix}$

with some help of symbolic octave:

$H=1/r_3*\begin{bmatrix}  
c_x*t_{31} + f_x*t_{11}& c_x*t_{32} + f_x*t_{12}& c_x*r_{3} + fx*r_{1}\\
c_y*t_{31} + f_y*t_{21}& c_y*t_{32} + f_y*t_{22}& c_y*r_{3} + fy*r_{2}\\
t_{31}& t_{32}& r_{3}
\end{bmatrix}$

The 3rd row of H is:

$H_{3}=1/r_3*\begin{bmatrix}  
t_{31}& t_{32}& r_{3}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}  
t_{31}/r_3& t_{32}/r_3& r_{3}/r_3
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}  
t_{31}/r_3& t_{32}/r_3& 1.0
\end{bmatrix}$

Now lets say I have image of two squares lying on the  same plane, only shifted through $X$ axis , this is my model:

[image: objects]

The square 2 is identical to square 1, but shifted with amount of 2 units in X axis.

I must state that both squares are on the X-Y plane, i.e. both have same rotation matrix against the camera coordinates. i.e. the first two rows of both extrinsic matrices are same.

Thus for first object, the last row of homography matrix is:
$H_{3,1}=\begin{bmatrix}  t_{31}/r_{3,1}& t_{32}/r_{3,1}& 1.0\end{bmatrix}$

For second object, the last row of homography matrix is:
$H_{3,2}=\begin{bmatrix}  t_{31}/r_{3,2}& t_{32}/r_{3,2}& 1.0\end{bmatrix}$

Member wise divide:

$H_{3,1} ./ H_{3,2}=\begin{bmatrix}  r_{3,2}/r_{3,1}& r_{3,2}/r_{3,1}& 1.0\end{bmatrix}$

As obvious the first two members are equal ($r_{3,2}/r_{3,1}$).

### Real world example

In action, these are values of computed homography matrices for above image:

$H_1 =\begin{bmatrix}
154.05&115.29&27\\
31.83&-70.807&252\\
-0.057042&0.11161&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

$H_2 =\begin{bmatrix}
178.42&127.13&374 \\
41.677&-80.555&354 \\
-0.044259&0.1161&1
\end{bmatrix}$

Note that I've double checked both matrices values and there where no error.

the ratio: $\alpha = H_2 ./ H_1$ (member wise divide)

$=\begin{bmatrix}
0.86341&0.90685&0.072193\\
0.76375&0.87899&0.71186\\
1.2888&0.96135&1
\end{bmatrix}$

As you can see the member $\alpha_{3,1}=1.2888$ and $\alpha_{3,2}=0.96135$ are not equal or even close together, but based on theory section, they should be equal.

Can anyone explain it?